# Remove all but the first N elements from a list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a list of items in the DOM and would like to prune it to only contain the first N items, perhaps using slice and remove.

What is the syntax in JQuery to remove any items after the first N?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKGN7/1/)

```
$("body").children().filter(":gt(5)").remove();
```

The above removes all the direct children of `body` with an index over 5. This is assuming `body` is the top of the DOM in question. if not, you can change `body` to be whatever the head of the DOM you want to "prune" is.

Comment: you put `#` in the actual id for your list, remove that. `#` is used in selectors to signify you are looking for an id... so `$("#list")` says to grab the element with an id of `list` http://jsfiddle.net/PKGN7/4/

Comment: Alternatively `$("body").children().slice(5).remove();` or `$("body").children(":gt(5)").remove();`